# Fixing the position of an image

Tags: graphics, floats

I am trying to set an image to a particular subsection by

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=4.0in]{sample.pdf}
 \caption{My sample}
 \label{fig:mysample}
\end{figure}
```

also tried:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=4.0in]{sample.pdf}
  \caption{My sample}
  \label{fig:mysample}
\end{figure}
```

However, it keeps appearing within the immediate section. How could I fix an image to a subsection?

Comment: `[h]` and `[!h]` are very restrictive an usually generate a warning, in particular they prevent the figure being placed at the top or bottom of the current page, or on a page on its own, so make it more likely that it goes to the end of the docuemnt. try `[htp]` or failing that see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275/1090

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `[htp]` seems to work but `minipage` is even better for what I was after